# Notes after bibliography entry with Biber and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, notes

I'm using `biblatex` with Biber as a backend. I need to add a one-sentence note, in bold, after a few of my references in the bibliography. These notes are not contained in my `.bib` file; they are specific to the paper I am currently working on. It has been suggested to me that I can just edit the `.bbl` file to include the note, but I'm not sure how to do this. Is this a viable solution? If so, how do I do it? If not, how can I achieve this in another way?

I'm using the nature citation style, if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can use `\DeclareSourcemap` to add a note filed to some bib-entries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to insert additional material in a `bbl` generated by `biber/BibLaTX` combination. You can add

```
\field{mynote}{<TEXT OF THE NOTE>}
```

in the appropriate entries. The one has to give the instruction to print it. A possible way to insert at the end of a bibenty (and in bold) is:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{mynote}{\textbf{#1}}
\AtEveryBibitem{
\csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{\iffieldundef{mynote}{}{\par\printfield{mynote}}}
}
```

Successive calls to `biber` will erase the modifications in the `bbl` file.

An alternative is to use `bibexport` to create a new BibTeX file containing only the entries in the current `tex` file, and then using the file generated by `bibexport` and inserting the notes specific to the paper there.

A further alternative is to use BibLaTeX facilities for external files. For this the option `loadfiles` has to be explicitly activated

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=nature,loadfiles=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
author = {Author, John},
title  = {Title},
journal =  {A Journal},
year = 2012,
}
@article{key2,
author = {Author2, John},
title  = {Title},
journal =  {A Journal},
year = 2012,
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Notes/note-key2.tex}
Note for \cite{key2}.  
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{\textbf{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{annotation}{
  \IfFileExists{Notes/note-\thefield{entrykey}.tex}{\par}{}
  \printfile[annotation]{Notes/note-\thefield{entrykey}.tex}
}

\AtEveryBibitem{
\csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{\usebibmacro{annotation}}
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Notes: Here I use a `Notes` directory that must be created before compiling the file. For the note files one can decide to use `filecontents` to include them  in the main source file or to generate independently only one time.

Comment: I had to use '\input' rather than '\printfile' to make it work, and move that to the '\IfFileExists' argument. Brilliant solution else!