# Biblatex-apa: numbered, annotated bibliography using \fullcitebib?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa6

**EDIT #3:** The code below has been updated to what I'm currently using, from the post at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91381/24264; note that I've added a field to my bibentry (`annote`) as part of this fix. I've decided to ***forgo adding the numbering***, since it seems to be more trouble than it's worth, and my prof may end up seeing it as against APA style, anyway :)

**EDIT #2:** I arrived at a satisfactory fix for the issue from EDIT #1 (reflected in the code below), but I would still like the annotation(s) to line up with the numbered references—"Howlin" and the word "Annotations" in my example. Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

**EDIT #1:** @Guido was very helpful with my main question. At this point, I'm trying to insert a "References" page that mimics the vertical spacing of `\printbibliography` in the current document—and I've, again, run into a gap in my knowledge.

*Original post:* My goal is to create an annotated bibliography in APA format (for a term paper due in April). Up to now, my only experience with biblatex is the simple `\printbibliography` command. Having done some searching, I was looking to replicate the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13655/24264), but I get no joy, even when I stick as closely as possible to Alan's original example; \fullcitebib itself works without a hitch, as long as Alan's code—starting with `\newcounter{bibnum}` and ending with `{\end{thebibliography}}`—is not present. When I insert the code block, I get the following errors at compile time:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\blx@precode ...egin {thebibliography}\thebibitem
l.91 \fullcitebib{howlin04}

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
...
l.91 \fullcitebib{howlin04}
```

My question (if you can call it a question, rather than a "please tell me how this is done") is why my MiKTeX seems to be behaving strangely—I don't have enough LaTeX knowledge to understand how `\thebibitem` is properly defined, and thus fix the problem.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[man,12pt,noextraspace]{apa6}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\shorttitle{Cog paper}

\begin{filecontents}{cogsources.bib} 
@article{howlin04,
author = {Howlin, Patricia and Goode, Susan and Hutton, Jane and Rutter, Michael},
title = {Adult outcome for children with autism},
journal = {Journal of Child Psychology and Psychiatry},
volume = {45},
number = {2},
publisher = {Blackwell Publishing},
issn = {1469-7610},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-7610.2004.00215.x},
doi = {10.1111/j.1469-7610.2004.00215.x},
pages = {212--229},
keywords = {Autistic disorder, prognosis, adulthood, follow-up studies},
year = {2004},
annote = {Annotations go here.},
}
\end{filecontents}

%% fontspec
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

%% bibliography
\usepackage[canadian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,language=american]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{cogsources.bib}

%% annote
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{annotation}
    {\finentry}
    {\setunit{\finentrypunct\par\vspace{\bibitemsep}\nobreak}
     \printfield{annotation}%
     \finentry}}    

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
\nocite{howlin04}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Sometimes the terms MWE is misleading: in you ca case we need the code that shows the problem, so we need the source code with your definition of the `\fullcitebib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13655/24264 must modified as follows: `\thebibitem` must be replaced with `\item`. Here is the resulting code

```
\newcounter{bibnum}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcitebib}
  {\renewenvironment*{thebibliography}
  {\list
     {\stepcounter{bibnum}\thebibnum.\ }
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{1.65\bibhang}
      %
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
  \begin{thebibliography}\item}
  {\usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}\finentry}
  {\item}
  {\end{thebibliography}}
```

Comment: @HarryBellemare If you want to print an annotated bibliography the proposed approach is not the best one. There are several ways to add annotations using biber. See [Notes after bibliography entry with Biber and biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83024/16895)

Comment: I see what you mean, but I have a reason for trying to do it this way: my professor has asked for 1-2 sentences under each of five headings (purpose, hypotheses, measures, results, implications) for the references I use, so adding a field or something similar doesn't seem like it would suit. Thanks for your many helpful suggestions.

Comment: @HarryBellemare If you need a few sentences for each paper using the `note` or `annote` field of `biblatex` and some minor customisation to the way they are printed in the file might be the best solution. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91304/16895

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that thread! I'm finally getting somewhere :) I think I will forgo the numbering.