# How to move the note field out and away from the main reference using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using `biblatex` to created a list of publications in an academic CV. I'd like to list my publications and outline my contribution to each publication after each listed publication.

My current idea is to modify the note field, for articles and books, so it moves out of the main reference and appears one line bellow the reference as shown below.

```
 (1) Smith, J. Journal of Silly Stuff, 20XX, XX, XXXX-XXXX

      My contribution to this paper was ...

 (2) Jones, W. Journal of .......

      My contribution to this paper was ...
```

My question is how do you think it is best I generate a list like that and is it possible to do it using biblatex using a modified field?

Comment: There are many different ways to do it. Partially it depends on the `biblatex` style used. Do you use `note` or `annote` for annoting the entries in your `bib` files. Which `biblatex` style of you use?

Comment: The style I'm using is `chem-rsc`. My entries are not annotated so the fields `note` and `annote` are free to be used for this.

Comment: I was playing with the `note` field as it was the first one I saw in jabref.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're ultimately wanting an annotated bibliography, I'd use the `annotation` field (or its alias `annote`). It typically isn't printed unless the bibliography style is already annotated. So you can just modify the `finentry` bibliography macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{annotation}
    {\finentry}
    {\setunit{\finentrypunct\par\vspace{\bibitemsep}\nobreak}
     \printfield{annotation}%
     \finentry}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct,markey,glashow}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `note` field is often printed in bibliography styles. So if you insist on using this field, you need to avoid printing it twice. This can be done by clearing `note` in the `begentry` bibliography macro and then restoring it in `finentry`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{note}
    {\undef\bbxnote}
    {\savefield{note}{\bbxnote}%
     \clearfield{note}}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \restorefield{note}{\bbxnote}%
  \iffieldundef{note}
    {\finentry}
    {\setunit{\finentrypunct\par\vspace{\bibitemsep}\nobreak}
     \printfield{note}%
     \finentry}}
```

Answer (score 6):

The use and position of notes depends, partially, on the `biblatex` style. Here is a solution independent of each style, except that it requires `biber` as the backend. The solution involves the use of the standard field `note` (or the *custom* field `mynote`) to store the text to be used for each entry's note.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib} 
@article{article01,
Author = {John Doe},
Journal = {Journal name},
Pages = {280--291},
Title = {Title},
Volume = {21},
Number = {1},
Year = {2013},
note = {My contribution to this paper was \dots}}
@article{article02,
Author = {John Doe},
Journal = {Journal name},
Pages = {280--291},
Title = {Title},
Volume = {21},
Number = {1},
Year = {2014},
note = {My contribution to this paper was \dots\dots}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{mynote}
\end{filecontents}  


\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=note]
      \step[fieldset=mynote, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=note, null]
    }
  }
}


\AtEveryBibitem{
\clearfield{note}
\csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{\iffieldundef{mynote}{}{\par\printfield{mynote}}}
}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The block

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{mynote}
\end{filecontents}
```

generates the `biblatex` configuration file `bib latex-dm.cfg` where we specify that we create a new custom field `mynote`.

Then we use the ability of `biber` to manipulate the `bib` files to copy the value of the `note` field to the entry `mynote`. This is achieved by  the block

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=note]
      \step[fieldset=mynote, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=note, null]
    }
  }
}
```

which also empties `note`.

Then we have to give  the instruction of how and  where to print the notes.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{
\clearfield{note}
\csappto{blx@bbx@\thefield{entrytype}}{\iffieldundef{mynote}{}{\par\printfield{mynote}}}
}
```

For every bibitem, we  clear the value of `note`; thus, one has the option to operate using `biber` or directly in `biblatex`. Then we patch the driver for the current entry by appending to it the text of a note (`mynote`).

[image]

Comment: Now it works. I'll delete my comments.