# Publications list of CV: Comments between references

Tags: bibtex

I'm currently putting together my CV to apply for postdoc positions.  After each paper in my publication list I want to put a short paragraph with an overview of the paper and exactly how I contributed to it.

I have been unable to figure out a way to do this cleanly and I'm currently using this workaround in BibDesk:

I click on the relevant publication and in the 'Year' field (which is usually the last field) I put the following:

```
2013 \newline \newline \begin{small} "text describing paper" \end{small}
```

This is quite a dirty workaround however as I am left with an additional full stop (  .) after the descriptive paragraph.  Also if the DOI field is used, it comes after the paragraph.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to better annotate references in a publications list?  I feel these descriptive paragraphs are critical for someone assessing my publication record.

Comment: biblatex has styles for annotated bibliographies - and probably there are some for bibtex, too. I would look for those rather than trying to force stuff into the year. Even using the note field would probably be better than trying to put it into year. Can you please post a Minimum Working Example with a sample of your current code?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)): it is unclear both how you are constructing your CV and how you are interacting with your bibliographic database.

Comment: If you are willing to use `biblatex` then you may want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149578/how-to-comment-references-in-a-bibliography/149643#149643

Comment: If you want to stick with `bibtex` then take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100594/annotated-bibliography

Comment: Thanks.  Using \bibliographystyle{annotate} solved my problem.