# Add Text/Comment into bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am using an additional bibliography inside my thesis. This includes only articles to which I contributed. Displaying these works fine, but I would like to add some comment before each cited paper. My code so far looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@misc{A2011,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2011},
  title = {A short title.},      
}
@misc{A2012,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2012},
  title = {Systems biology and personalized medicine are two emerging research areas, which promise to transform our health system.},
}
@misc{A2013,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2013},
  title = {This title is not so short.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\defbibnote{myprenote}{This thesis is based on the following original publications:}
\nocite{A2012, A2013}
\printbibliography[prenote=myprenote,title={List of original publications}]
\end{document}
```

This adds paper 2 and 3 to the bibliography, but I cannot enter a comment above it.
I made a short visualization what I am trying to get:

[image]

This piece of code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149578/how-to-comment-references-in-a-bibliography) tex.sx article adds a comment to the bibliography.

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{mynote}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptobibmacro{finentry}{\par\printfield{mynote}}{}{}
```

But how can I add the commment before the entry (as indicated by the arrows in the image above)?

Comment: Should the text appear at the beginning just after the title "Bibliography", or do you want to be able to insert text in arbitrary positions, between some entries?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I would like to add the text after the `myprenote` text and directly before the reference. So basically free positioned, I have added a picture above to make it clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to comment references in a bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149578/how-to-comment-references-in-a-bibliography)

Comment: This is _not a duplicate!_ This one wants a comment as well, but at a diffent place!

Comment: @tohecz but the answer is more or less identical.

Comment: @StrongBad Ok, then you can, of course, edit the second question, edit the answer accordingly, and close this one (I can't do it, since I have no clue as what's going on in biblatex).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two issues with adding a "note" before every item. The first issue is getting the "note" and the second issue is printing the note.

Using the `bibtex8` backend for `biblatex` constrains the fields that can be used in your bib file. For this application, you would probably want to use the `note` field, although this will cause problems for any entries that need the note field to carry extra information. If you can use `biber` as the backend then you can define your own fields and data model.

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{mynote}
```

and then you do not have to worry about clashes.

Printing the note before the entry is easier than after the entry since there is the `\AtEveryBibitem` hook. The only trick is that the bibliography is in a list environment so you need an `\item` and not a `\par` after the note. You also need to clear the note field so it is not used later. You can add the note with

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\printfield{note}\clearfield{note}\item}
```

A full MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A2011,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2011},
  title = {A short title.},      
  note = {This source is really interesting because it doesn't have a real title}
}
@misc{A2012,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2012},
  title = {Systems biology and personalized medicine are two emerging research areas, which promise to transform our health system.},
  note = {This second source is also really interesting because it contains words}
}
@misc{A2013,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2013},
  title = {This title is not so short.},
  note = {This third source is not interesting}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\AtEveryBibitem{\printfield{note}\clearfield{note}\item}
\begin{document}
\defbibnote{myprenote}{This thesis is based on the following original publications:}
\nocite{A2012, A2013}
\printbibliography[prenote=myprenote,title={List of original publications}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't use the `note` field, so this would work. At the moment the note also appears in the reference, can it be suppressed there selectively?

Comment: @Chris oppps, I missed that. I fixed it.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks. I am currently not using Biber since it doesn't work and I have to find out why. But this is a project on my list, once I have turned my thesis. At the moment I am not changing any packets.

Comment: One additional question: Can this be different when more than one bibliography is used (meaning one bibliography displays the notes as described above and another one suppresses them completely)?

Comment: @Chris this seems like something that may have been asked before. If not, you should probably ask it as a new question with an MWE.

Comment: Ok, I will do that later.