# How to add a note to myself in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, biber

How can I add a comment to myself in a .bib file to be read by biber?  I've checked out answers like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159806/109880) but they are about adding comments for readers to see, whereas I'm only looking to add these for personal documentation.

Comment: What about using `%` to identify the comments?

Comment: See also [Are comments discouraged in a BibTeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261261/35864)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything in a `.bib` file that isn't part of an entry is a comment, so you can just type. Here are some examples of comments in a bib file.

```
This is a comment

Now here's an entry:
@BOOK{blah,
    ...
}

% You can also use markers, if you want, but they're unnecessary

If you need to comment out an entry, the @COMMENT can be useful

@COMMENT Even though this looks like an entry, it isn't @BOOK{blah,
...
}

Actually, btxdoc recommends just leaving off the @ like this:
BOOK{blah,
    This still is a comment even though it could look like any other entry
}
```