# Shorthands for bibitems with them and without space before other items

Tags: biblatex, spacing

I have used the approach in this question: [Add Text/Comment into bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159806/add-text-comment-into-bibliography?noredirect=1&lq=1)
in order to print shorthands before my bibitems (that have them).

I want them on the same line, so I modified the code to use a spacing command `\quad` after each shorthand instead of a new `\item`:

`\\AtEveryBibitem{\printfield{shorthand}\clearfield{shorthand}\quad}`

But I would like to suppress the space that `\quad` generates before bibitems that do not have any shorthand to print.

Maybe there is a spacing command that will be suppressed if nothing is printed before it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Vismann2017Lagen-och-arkiv,
    Author = {Cornelia Vismann},
    Publisher = {Gl{\"a}nta produktion},
    Shorttitle = {Lagen och arkivet},
    Title = {Lagen och arkivet : Akternas mediehistoria},
    Year = {2017},
    }
@book{sou2018:25,
    Address = {Stockholm},
    Author = {Digitaliseringsr{\"a}ttsutredningen},
    Keywords = {sou},
    Publisher = {Norstedts juridik},
    Shorthand = {SOU 2018:25},
    Title = {Juridik som st{\"o}d f{\"o}r f{\"o}rvaltningens digitalisering},
    Year = {2018},  
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{\printfield{shorthand}\clearfield{shorthand}\quad}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Vismann2017Lagen-och-arkiv,sou2018:25}

\printbibliography[keyword=sou,title={Utredningsbet{\"a}nkanden}]
\nopagebreak
\printbibliography[notkeyword=sou]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The title is less than clear, but I cannot really think of a better one right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `\setunit` should help in situations like this.
But there are two obstacles for `\setunit` here

1. `\AtEveryBibitem` does not play nice with `\setunit`, you could use `\renewbibmacro{begentry}` instead (and indeed that is what I suggest).
2. Even then `\setunit` will have issues when authors are replaced by a dash (the dash is typeset as is and not with `\printtext`, which means that the punctuation tracker is thrown off).

So my preferred solution

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printfield{shorthand}%
  \clearfield{shorthand}%
  \setunit{\quad}}
```

is out in this case. Hence I have to suggest the more awkward

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {}
    {\printfield{shorthand}%
     \clearfield{shorthand}%
     \quad}}
```

Which gives

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {}
    {\printfield{shorthand}%
     \clearfield{shorthand}%
     \quad}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,kant:kpv,kant:ku}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: quad between the <code>shorthand</code> and the rest of the entry]

BTW: Are you aware of `\printbiblist{shorthand}`? (Best used with Biber instead of BibTeX(8)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibcheck{noshorthand}{\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\skipentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,kant:kpv,kant:ku}

\printbiblist{shorthand}
\printbibliography[check=noshorthand]
\end{document}
```

[image: Two bibliography lists: One list of shorthands, one normal bibliography. The list of shorthands has the shorthands as labels in the left margin.]

Comment: That's perfect. Will accept this in 7 min, when I am allowed. ;-)